# Excel VBA Range.Find: xlPart vs xlWhole

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am trying to find a cell which contains exactly "FTEs" string. When I use `xlPart` it finds it but I need it working with `xlWhol`e because it could be a substring and I don't want that to be found.

The issue is that the cell which `xlPart` finds contains exactly "FTEs" string and `xlWhole` fails to find it. I have added the screenshot of my watches at the line where this `.Find` is. You can clearly see that the search string matches the cell's value exactly. You can see that `xlPart` finds it and `xlWhole` does not.

Could someone explain how that is possible? Are there other things `.Find` considers that I am not aware of?

[image: Watch]

Comment: Could there be any hidden characters or errant spaces?

Comment: Subject to @SJR's comment, what does `=LEN(<cell with 'FTEs'>)` return?

Comment: You mention substring but are you looking for a match based on the **entire** contents of a cell, or a **whole word**?

Comment: SJR - no;  Jeeped, it is 4 for both cell value and the string; CLR, I need the entire cell's value to be the exact match to the string

Comment: Well, I've managed to get it working with Application.Match but it doesn't seem to be the right way to do that and I am really curious why .Find option still doesn't work.